# I need help to improve the execution time of retrieving SSL certificates

Tags: c++, c, performance, ssl, optimization

I am working on a project that grabs the SSL certificate from a site and extracts the CName field. I currently have the execution down to 0.435s but I'm certain it can be improved more so I wanted to leverage the stackoverflow community to find all the places I'm wasting cycles or could be doing it quicker. below is the code I have so far to retrieve a SSL certificate and extract the CName field.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    struct sockaddr_in sa;
    SSL*     ssl;
    X509*    server_cert;

    SSLeay_add_ssl_algorithms();
    SSL_load_error_strings();
    SSL_CTX* ctx = SSL_CTX_new (SSLv23_method());

    int sd = ::socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);//create socket
    if (sd!=-1 && ctx!=NULL)
    {
        memset (&sa, '\0', sizeof(sa));
        sa.sin_family      = AF_INET;
        sa.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr ("SOME IP");   /* Server IP */
        sa.sin_port        = htons     (443);           /* Server Port number */

        int err = ::connect(sd, (struct sockaddr*) &sa, sizeof(sa));
        if (err!=-1)
        {
            ssl = SSL_new (ctx);
            if (ssl!=NULL)
            {
                SSL_set_fd(ssl, sd);
                err = SSL_connect(ssl);
                if (err!=-1)
                {
                    server_cert = SSL_get_peer_certificate(ssl);
                    if (server_cert!=NULL)
                    {
                        printf("%s\n", strrchr(X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_subject_name(server_cert), 0, 0),'=')+1);
                        X509_free (server_cert);
                    }
                }
                SSL_free (ssl);
            }
            ::close(sd);//close socket
        }
    }
    SSL_CTX_free (ctx);
}
```

The two areas where it seems like I could shave off some CPU cycles is at ::connect where I'm guessing it might be doing more work than I need, and at the printf line where I'm extracting the CN= field at the end of the SSL subject.

I may very well be at the lowest possible level and any further optimizations won't be worth the time but I look forward to being proven wrong on that point.

My guess is there's a way I could go a level deeper and implement just the first 2 steps of SSL/TLS handshake process which is all that's required to obtain the server certificate but a couple hours of googling hasn't shown a way to do that, though that's probably due to my Google-Fu skills. In an regard I look forward to learning some optimization tricks or finding out I'm as performant as I'm going to get!

Comment: I´m not into C++ or C so I cannot help you from this standpoint. Just one question, do you test with actual SSL servers on the internet ? 
Setting up something locally would be wise for testing, this should eliminate any latency so you get accurate results

Comment: Your code is not working for servers sharing multiple SSL hosts on a single IP address, you need to send the correct host name in order to get the right certificate.

Comment: That's a good point. Though I wonder if removing the latency of the internet would give you false data since eventually I am going to have to test it against live hosts. When i run the tests I run it 100 times and average the times to try and eliminate some of the jitter due to internet latency.

Comment: *which is all that's required to obtain the server certificate* You can't trust a peer without finishing handshake. It can send any another certificate and you may not trust it if handshake is not finished (the certificate is not validated).

Comment: This is probably not a problem with your code but with the network, so unless you can minimize that impact you're stuck. Note, benchmark this and observe *CPU time* vs. *wall-clock time*. This code is probably quite optimized, there's nothing else you can do to speed it up dramatically.

Comment: @S.M. so for this project I'm just interested in what it certificate it offers. If it's lying to me, sobeit. I don't want to make a full connection anyway or send/receive any data. I just want the certificate that https://<SOME IP>:443/ returns when asked for it in the quickest possible time. I definitely agree though in a fuller context you would want to finish the handshake to make sure everything is trusted.

Comment: @tadman is there a profiling tool you recommend? I've just been using the `time` command at the start of the execution.

Comment: `time` is a great place to start, but there are others that are OS specific. Just learn to read the output of `time` to understand more about what's going on and where to start optimizing. If you're doing this on your home connection it will be a lot slower than, say, a VPS located in a good datacentre.

Comment: Which version of SSL/TLS do you use and what is the version of the remote server? TLS 1.3 add a way to avoid unnecessary handchecks. It provide a minimal support for a 0-RTT handcheck (unsafe if this is the first connection, the server must also support this option).

Answer (score 0):

It seems internet latency was my biggest time sink, as was mentioned in the comments. I ran the code above against a host geographically near the code host vs the other side of the county and went from 0.429 to 0.172!